# Mysql - Creating a stub table that holds the Id's of certain rows in another table

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, structure

I'm working on a project where I need to have different kinds of users, victims and members. The database should be able to support large amounts of records for users, say, for example 500k, but it's very reasonable that it grows even larger.

Currently I have all of these records stored in the same table, "users", with a role field that describes what type of user it is. Initially this table was split in two, one for victims and one for members, but having a single table simplifies a lot of other work on the project.

For the most part, there will be a much higher number of victims than members, which makes querying for victims not that much of a deal, because most of the rows will be victims. However, when needing to query for members (especially things like counting the number of rows which are members) I would assume it would waste a lot of time looking at rows that end up not being the ones I want.

My solution to this was to create a stub "members" table, that all it does is hold the id's of the rows in the user's table which are infact members, consisting only of a primary key + foreign key unsigned integer.

Does this solution actually mitigate the amount of time it would take to query for members ? What would be the best solution ? Again, I'm assuming that splitting the table into two separate ones would be the best option, and if that's the only reasonable way I'll choose that one, but having all in the same table does fix a bunch of other problems.

Comment: If you create an index on the "type" column of your User table, I'd think that would be used for simple count(*) of members with a particular type. But, I assume there are other queries you need. In general, even before doing this, don't assume there will be a performance problem: test it and see if you have one.

Comment: Actually, neither an index nor a subtable will help much if you are trying to pull large quantities.  Almost all optimizers will go to full table scans.  In the case that you know which one you want, the index on the first table will suffice.  Think of it this way - the lower the data distribution (number of types) there are in a table, the less effective an index will be. Creating another table with member_ids may reduce the overall number of records returned, but 500,000 is not really a very big number to query against.  What database are you using? - sorry - I meant "database engine"

Answer (score 1):

Remember the old days, when a search engine would say "Found 2,571,462 hits"?  Did you believe the number?  Probably the number changed while you were reading it.

Then they got smart and said "About 2,570,000 hits".  Clearly an approximation.  Perhaps estimated by some algorithm or counted once a day.

Then came "Over 2,000,000 hits".

And now no mention.

I suggest that you can count once a day, then say "About 1,234 members".

The lesson here...  Not all technical problems can (or even should) be solved in code.  Some should be solved by changing the user's expectations.